# LINQ to XML query and an extension method that converts an XML document to an XDocument

Tags: linq-to-xml

Here is my XML document that is passed into the `CreateListOfAddresses()` method:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <AddressValidateResponse>
        <Address ID="0">
        <Address2>8 WILDWOOD DR</Address2>
        <City>OLD LYME</City>
        <State>CT</State>
        <Zip5>06371</Zip5>
        <Zip4>1844</Zip4>
    </Address>
</AddressValidateResponse>
```

Here is my method:

```
    private List<AddressBlockResponse> CreateListOfAddresses(XmlDocument xmlDoc)
    {
        // Convert XML document to xdocument so we can use LINQ.
        XDocument xDoc = xmlDoc.ToXDocument();

        var address = from a in xDoc.Descendants("AddressValidateResponse")
                      select new AddressBlockResponse
                      {
                          Order = int.Parse(a.Attribute("ID").Value),
                          AddressLine2 = a.Element("Address2").Value,
                          City = a.Element("City").Value,
                          State = a.Element("State").Value,
                          ZipCode = a.Element("Zip5").Value,
                          ZipPlus4 = a.Element("Zip4").Value
                      };
        return address.ToList();
    }
```

Here is the extension method that converts my XML document to an XDocument type:

```
public static XDocument ToXDocument(this XmlDocument xmlDocument)
{
    using (var nodeReader = new XmlNodeReader(xmlDocument))
    {
        nodeReader.MoveToContent();
        return XDocument.Load(nodeReader);
    }
}
```

Here is my object:

```
[Serializable]
public struct AddressBlockResponse
{
    // Standardized address returned from the service
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public int Order;

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public string AddressLine1;

    [DataMember(IsRequired = false)]
    public string AddressLine2;

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public string City;

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public string State;

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public string ZipCode;

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public string ZipPlus4;
}
```

Here is my problem: the CreateListOfAddresses() method returns

> Enumeration yielded no results

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your issue is that AddressValidateResponse is the root node of your document.

You should change it to:

```
var address = from a in xDoc.Descendants("Address")
                  select new AddressBlockResponse
                  {
                      // stuff
                  };
```

Also when you are using xelements like

```
City = a.Element("City").Value,
```

You should do:

```
City = (string)a.Element("City"),
```

because if the element doesn't exist your program will throw a null reference exception.  I know you will probably always have these xml nodes but I think it is just a good habit.